# Find loop in Tree preferred in java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a set data in DB item-folder hierarchy (like in snapshot)

I have a loop in the data

like A->B , B->C C->D , C->A

[image]

The code looks like:

```
public class Vertex {

    private String label;
    private boolean beingVisited;
    private boolean visited;
    private List<Vertex> adjacencyList;

    public Vertex(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.adjacencyList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNeighbor(Vertex adjacent) {
        this.adjacencyList.add(adjacent);
    }
    //getters and setters
}

public class Graph {

    private List<Vertex> vertices;

    public Graph() {
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addVertex(Vertex vertex) {
       if(!vertices.contains(vertex)){
        this.vertices.add(vertex);
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(Vertex from, Vertex to) {
        from.addNeighbor(to);
    }

   // ...

   public boolean hasCycle(Vertex sourceVertex) {
    sourceVertex.setBeingVisited(true);

    for (Vertex neighbor : sourceVertex.getAdjacencyList()) {
        if (neighbor.isBeingVisited()) {
            // backward edge exists
            return true;
        } else if (!neighbor.isVisited() && hasCycle(neighbor)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    sourceVertex.setBeingVisited(false);
    sourceVertex.setVisited(true);
    return false;
}

  public boolean hasCycle() {
    for (Vertex vertex : vertices) {
        if (!vertex.isVisited() && hasCycle(vertex)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

//MAIN

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      Graph graph = new Graph();
        ResultSet rs = provider.conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT itemId, folder FROM SnapshotData);

            while (rs.next()) {



          Vertex vertexFrom = new Vertex(rs.getString("itemId"));
           Vertex vertexTo = new Vertex(rs.getString("folder"));

            graph.addVertex(vertexFrom);
            graph.addVertex(vertexTo);
            graph.addEdge(vertexFrom, vertexTo);

         }
        assertTrue(graph.hasCycle());

    }
```

I'm stuck what i'm missing

Comment: You have forgotten to write what have you got. The standard set: 1. I am doing this, 2. I am awaiting this, 3. I am getting this instead. Don't make us do extra work!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your problem is the creation of your nodes.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Vertex vertexFrom = new Vertex(rs.getString("itemId"));
    Vertex vertexTo = new Vertex(rs.getString("folder"));
    graph.addEdge(vertexFrom, vertexTo);
}
```

If we take your screenshot you have 5 elements (A, B, C, D, F), but you are creating 10 (2xA, 2xB, 4xC, 1xF. so there is no loop because your graph look like this:

```
A---B

B---C

C---D

C---A

C---F
```

I suggest to save your nodes you created in a set/HashMap and if they already exist take it from there and when not create it new. Something like this (didn't test it):

```
Map<String,Vertex> verticesList = new HashMap<String,Vertex>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String from = rs.getString("itemId");
    Vertex vertexFrom = null;
    if(verticesList.contains(from)){
        vertexFrom = verticesList.get(from);
    } else {
        vertexFrom = new Vertex(from);
        verticesList.put(from,vertexFrom);
    }
    ... //same for the other vertex
    graph.addEdge(vertexFrom, vertexTo);
}
```

@Edit: A runnable example:

**Graph:**

```
public class Graph {

    private List<Vertex> vertices;

    public Graph() {
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addVertex(Vertex vertex) {
        if (!vertices.contains(vertex)) {
            this.vertices.add(vertex);
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(Vertex from, Vertex to) {
        from.addNeighbor(to);
    }

    public boolean hasCycle(Vertex sourceVertex) {
        sourceVertex.setBeingVisited(true);

        for (Vertex neighbor : sourceVertex.getAdjacencyList()) {
            if (neighbor.isBeingVisited()) {
                // backward edge exists
                return true;
            } else if (!neighbor.isVisited() && hasCycle(neighbor)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        sourceVertex.setBeingVisited(false);
        sourceVertex.setVisited(true);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasCycle() {
        for (Vertex vertex : vertices) {
            if (!vertex.isVisited() && hasCycle(vertex)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Vertex:**

```
public class Vertex {

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    private String label;

    public boolean isBeingVisited() {
        return beingVisited;
    }

    public void setBeingVisited(boolean beingVisited) {
        this.beingVisited = beingVisited;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    private boolean beingVisited;

    public List<Vertex> getAdjacencyList() {
        return adjacencyList;
    }

    public void setAdjacencyList(List<Vertex> adjacencyList) {
        this.adjacencyList = adjacencyList;
    }

    private boolean visited;
    private List<Vertex> adjacencyList;

    public Vertex(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.adjacencyList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNeighbor(Vertex adjacent) {
        this.adjacencyList.add(adjacent);
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph graph = new Graph();
        String[][] rs = new String[5][2];
        rs[0][0] = "A";
        rs[0][1] = "B";
        rs[1][0] = "B";
        rs[1][1] = "C";
        rs[2][0] = "C";
        rs[2][1] = "D";
        rs[3][0] = "C";
        rs[3][1] = "A";
        rs[4][0] = "C";
        rs[4][1] = "F";

        HashMap<String,Vertex> verticesList = new HashMap<String,Vertex>();


        for(int i = 0; i<rs.length;i++){
            String from = rs[i][0];
            String to = rs[i][1];
            System.out.println("From: " + from + " to: " + to);

            Vertex vertexFrom;
            Vertex vertexTo;
            if (verticesList.containsKey(from)) {
                vertexFrom = verticesList.get(from);
            } else {
                vertexFrom = new Vertex(from);
                verticesList.put(from,vertexFrom);
            }
            if (verticesList.containsKey(to)) {
                vertexTo = verticesList.get(to);
            } else {
                vertexTo = new Vertex(to);
                verticesList.put(to,vertexTo);
            }
            graph.addVertex(vertexTo);
            graph.addVertex(vertexFrom);
            graph.addEdge(vertexFrom, vertexTo);
        }
        System.out.println(graph.hasCycle());
        System.out.println(verticesList.size());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
From: A to: B
From: B to: C
From: C to: D
From: C to: A
From: C to: F
true
5
```

Comment: I was missing in the code  
graph.addVertex(folder); - edited

Comment: @VitalyT still the same problem

Comment: @VitalyT was to lazy to do the same for vertexTo that's why see the comment above graph.addEdge. You have to do the same as for vertexFrom (copy paste or use a function to reduce duplicate code)

Comment: you mean ?         while (rs.next()) {
    String from = rs.getString("itemId");
    String to = rs.getString("folder");
    Vertex vertexFrom;
    Vertex vertexTo;
    if (verticesList.containsKey(from)) {
     vertexFrom = verticesList.get(from);
    } else {
     vertexFrom = new Vertex(from);
    }
    if (verticesList.containsKey(to)) {
     vertexTo = verticesList.get(to);
    } else {
     vertexTo = new Vertex(to);
    }
    //... //same for the other vertex
    graph.addVertex(vertexFrom);
    graph.addVertex(vertexTo);
    graph.addEdge(vertexFrom, vertexTo);
   }

Comment: yes exactly you can check at the end if the map only contains 5 elements. Ah I forgot something: you have to add the vertices in the map at the end of course. see my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204673/discussion-between-boendal-and-vitalyt).

Comment: @VitalyT I tested the code myself and it worked without a problem. Maybe something with your sql failed? I will update my post with the code you can try it yourself (it's without sql but works without a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

1. As I see, your prog won't work simply because it counts edges in one direction only, but if we want to check a graph to be a tree, we don't use the orientation of edges.

That way you will never find the cycle a-b, b-c, a-c.

2. If you want to check an algorithm, count its intermediate results by hand and check them - all of them, not only the final one. It is your work, not ours.
3. Put here all appropriate code. As I see, the of your example problem is not in `hasCycle` method. I would check getters/setters.